# Error specifying character argument for GTS in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have 3 tiers of product which I'm creating a hierarchical forecast for using the gts function from the [hts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/hts.pdf) in R.

My tiers are:

- PL1: A3
- PL2: AT
- PL3: ATA,ATB,ATD,ATH,ATI,ATJ

In reality I have many more, but I limited the structure to this subset as I'm just learning this package. Each PL3 has 40 time observations.

Following this [tutorial from Hyndsight](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/gts/), I was able to get something working. However I don't think I'm specifying the character argument correctly.

```
myts=ts(matrix(data.agg$SalesUnits,ncol=6,nrow=40))

blnames <- unique(paste(data.agg$Group.2, # PL2
                 data.agg$Group.3, # PL3
                 data.agg$Group.4,  # PL4
                 sep=""))

colnames(myts)=blnames

gy=gts(myts,characters=c(2,2,3))

fc=forecast(gy)
```

According to the documentation, specifying a numeric vector for characters implies a non-hierarchy?

> Because none of these is hierarchical, we could specify characters = list(3, 1, 1), or as a simple numeric vector: characters = c(3, 1, 1). This implies its non-hierarchical structure and its characters segments

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to specify the correct character argument. When I try to use lists, the function fails. While my code works as written, I don't think it's correct because the output says there are only 2 levels:

```
Grouped Time Series 
2 Levels 
Number of groups at each level: 1 6 
Total number of series: 7 
Number of observations in each historical series: 40 
Number of forecasts per series: 10
```

Comment: Are you able to share the data on the site? Just looking at your code, I'm not able to know what's the problem. If the data is confidential, you may like to simulate the data but use the same bottom-level names. Also if there are more than 4 groups in the structure, it's better to use `groups` argument for specifying the grouping structure rather than `characters` argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I was using gts where I should have been using hts. That resolved my issue